# Could not resolve host: >

Tags: python

I am trying to issue a curl command from python, from command line it works fine :

```
curl -k --data-binary @GetRequestData.xml -u archala:H@ror1987 https://wsgwtestmg.mass.gov:5550/service/mgmt/current > Response\generated_Resp.xml
```

but when I called it from python :

```
from sys import argv
import subprocess
# run python cache2.py hosts.txt Test
with open(argv[1]) as f:
  addresses = {i.split(" : ")[0] : i.split(" : ")[1] for i in f}
  print(addresses[argv[2]])


command = "curl -k --data-binary @GetRequestData.xml -u archala:H@ror1987 https://" +addresses[argv[2]].strip()+ ":5550/service/mgmt/current > Response\generated_Resp.xml"
print(command)
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

I got  :
 Could not resolve host: >

Comment: What is the output of `print(command)`?

Comment: Where do you think you set `https://wsgwtestmg.mass.gov` in the code?

Comment: https://wsgwtestmg.mass.gov come from the command line from addresses[argv[2]]

Comment: print(command) out put exactly what I put in the command line.

Comment: Your command line is redirecting stdout to a file with ">".  I believe you need the shell=True to do that, but you are also capturing stdout with Popen (stdout=subprocess.PIPE), so why not just remove everything after ">".  Usually, Popen is captured as "p", then communicate() is called to return the stdout/stderr streams.  You are actually capturing stdout into "p".

Comment: That is not a very pythonic way of doing things.  You should use something like [Requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks swstephe, I added  shell=True and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of swstephe , added  shell=True, it worked.

someone mentioned using  Requests is a better way, I will appreciated if someone gave me the same using  Requests.
Thanks.